# JavaScript: Combile / Simplify multiple ajax Requests

Tags: ajax, parse-platform

I am building a service app and requires multiple request, is there a common way to combine the services, I have at least 26 services on queue. Here are the first two? What is the preferred process to guarantee error handling? Set high timeouts for each call? any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
/*
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// ObjectivesGoals
 */
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'get',
    url: serverDomain + '/classes/ObjectivesGoals',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': appID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': restID,
        'X-Parse-Session-Token': sessionToken
    }
}).then(function (httpResponse) {
    var createObjectives = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
    var objectives = createObjectives.results;
    constructPage();
    response.success('hi again');
}, function (httpResponse) {
    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse);
});

/*
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Achievements
*/
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'get',
    url: serverDomain + '/classes/Achievements',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': appID,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key': restID,
        'X-Parse-Session-Token': sessionToken
    }

}).then(function (httpResponse) {
    var createAchievements = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
    var achievements = createAchievements.results;
    constructPage();
    response.success('hi again');
}, function (httpResponse) {
    console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse);
});
```

Comment: Hi, you want to run them in parallel or one after the other? Is the next function is depended on the result of the previous function ?

Comment: parallel, they don't depend on each other.

Comment: did you consider to use this one: https://github.com/caolan/async there is an option to run multiple requests in parallel